# How to access an object created inside a function outside

Tags: python, function

I have the following function:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from future.utils import iteritems
from builtins import range, input
# Note: you may need to update your version of future
# sudo pip install -U future

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from kmeans import plot_k_means, get_simple_data, cost

def cost(X, R, M):
    cost = 0
    for k in range(len(M)):
        # method 1
        # for n in range(len(X)):
        #     cost += R[n,k]*d(M[k], X[n])

        # method 2
        diff = X - M[k]
        sq_distances = (diff * diff).sum(axis=1)
        cost += (R[:,k] * sq_distances).sum()
    return cost

def plot_k_means(X, K, max_iter=20, beta=3.0, show_plots=False):
    N, D = X.shape
    # R = np.zeros((N, K))
    exponents = np.empty((N, K))

    # initialize M to random
    initial_centers = np.random.choice(N, K, replace=False)
    M = X[initial_centers]

    costs = []
    k = 0
    for i in range(max_iter):
        k += 1
        # step 1: determine assignments / resposibilities
        # is this inefficient?
        for k in range(K):
            for n in range(N):
                exponents[n,k] = np.exp(-beta*d(M[k], X[n]))
        R = exponents / exponents.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)


        # step 2: recalculate means
        # decent vectorization
        # for k in range(K):
        #     M[k] = R[:,k].dot(X) / R[:,k].sum()
        # oldM = M

        # full vectorization
        M = R.T.dot(X) / R.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True).T
        # print("diff M:", np.abs(M - oldM).sum())

        c = cost(X, R, M)
        costs.append(c)
        if i > 0:
            if np.abs(costs[-1] - costs[-2]) < 1e-5:
                break

        if len(costs) > 1:
            if costs[-1] > costs[-2]:
                pass
                # print("cost increased!")
                # print("M:", M)
                # print("R.min:", R.min(), "R.max:", R.max())

    if show_plots:
        plt.plot(costs)
        plt.title("Costs")
        plt.show()

        random_colors = np.random.random((K, 3))
        colors = R.dot(random_colors)
        plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=colors)
        plt.show()

    #print("Final cost", costs[-1])
    final_cost = costs[-1]
    print(final_cost)
    
    return M, R, final_cost


def get_simple_data():
    # assume 3 means
    D = 2 # so we can visualize it more easily
    s = 4 # separation so we can control how far apart the means are
    mu1 = np.array([0, 0])
    mu2 = np.array([s, s])
    mu3 = np.array([0, s])

    N = 900 # number of samples
    X = np.zeros((N, D))
    X[:300, :] = np.random.randn(300, D) + mu1
    X[300:600, :] = np.random.randn(300, D) + mu2
    X[600:, :] = np.random.randn(300, D) + mu3
    return X


def main():
    X = get_simple_data()

    plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
    plt.show()

    costs = np.empty(10)
    costs[0] = None
    
    for k in range(1, 10):
        M, R, final_cost = plot_k_means(X, k, show_plots=False)
        c = cost(X, R, M)
        costs[k] = c
    

    plt.plot(costs)
    plt.title("Cost vs K")
    plt.show()

    print(costs)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I want access costs from inside the main() but if just print(costs) i do not get the correct values. Need help here?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
costs = []
for k in range(1, 10):
    M, R, final_cost = plot_k_means(X, k, show_plots=False)
    costs.append(final_cost)

print(costs)
```